# Left arm of Android logo is not visible

Tags: html, css

I am learning to code via The Odin Project.  I'm attempting to recreate the Android logo using HTML CSS3 from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-android-logo

Their code from the exercise is located on the above link.

However, I can not seem to get the left arm to be visible. I've tried: 
 1. Chrome
 2. Firefox
[image: android logo]

```
<div class="android">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="l_ant"></div>
        <div class="r_ant"></div>
        <div class="l_eye"></div>
        <div class="r_eye"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="l_arm"></div>
        <div class="r_arm"></div>
        <div class="l_leg"></div>
        <div class="r_leg"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

div div {
background: #a4ca39;
position: relative;
}

.adroid {
height: 404px;
width: 334px;
margin: 100px auto;
}

.head {
width: 220px;
height: 100px;
top: 32px;
border-radius: 110px 100px 0 0;
}

.l_eye, .r_eye {
background: #fff;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 42px;
}

    .l_eye {
left: 50px;
}

.r_eye {
right: 50px;
}

.l_ant, .r_ant {
width: 6px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: -34px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.l_ant {
left: 50px;
text-transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.r_ant {
right: 50px;
text-transform: rotate(30deg);
}


.body {
width: 220px;
height: 184px;
top: 40px;
border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}


    .l_arm {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

    .r_arm, .l_leg, .r_leg {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

    .l_arm {
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

    .r_arm {
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 25px;

}

    .l_leg, .r_leg {
    height: 80px;
    top: 182px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}

    .l_arm {
    left: -58px;
}

    .r_arm {
    right: -58px;
}

    .l_leg {
    left: 45px;
}

    .r_leg {
    right: 45px;
}
```

[image: css1]
[image: css2]
[image: css3]

Comment: the code you posted seems to be missing the entire part of your css code ? could you show us in a fiddle maybe ?

Comment: Thank you @MageshKumaar. Just pasted the rest of the CSS. See anything?

Comment: OT: You should buy a licence if you like ST ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `.l_arm` class is set to `left:-58px` which pushes it 58 pixels off the screen to the left. Try changing this to `left:0` and shift every other div 58 pixels to the right. Since there is no other content on the page, `position:absolute` on `.l_arm` has the (x, y) origin point at (0,0), meaning if you set `left` to a negative value it will appear off-screen.

Comment: There is the *android* div. The CSS for it isn't posted, but it should be enough to position it more to the right.

Comment: I just posted the rest of the CSS @vals.

Comment: Found it. While I was correcting the formatting of this answer I noticed my css typo. ".adroid" instead of ".android".  Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.